# jqplot to retrieve results from php-mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jqplot

I am having problems plotting my pie chart using jqplot.

After getting my results from php i have converted it to json using json_encode. The output is

```
{"a":2,"b":1,"c":5,"d":650}
```

Now when i try to put these results into my javascript

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // method 1
    //var data1 = document.getElementById("dataArray").value;
    //eval('data1 = '+data+';');

    // method 2
    var data1 = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

    var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('Chart', [data1], 
    { 
        seriesDefaults: {
            // Make this a pie chart.
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
            rendererOptions: {
                // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        }, 
        legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
    }
    );
});
</script>
```

I've tried two methods, the first to put it inside a hidden field, and the second to retrieve straight from PHP. Both of which result in `Uncaught. No plot target specified` errors in my Chrome console.

What is it I am doing wrong here?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Is `Chart` an actual element? Is it loaded when this script runs?

Comment: omg you are such a genius. what an idiot i was. it works now. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Asad mentioned, my stupid mistake was that `Chart` was not specified as an element. So yeah if anyone else ever comes into the same problem, be sure to check that out. :)